# php fputcsv of nested array.

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

Can someone please help me I have set of data which I'm sorting out by regular expression. I have correct result, but when I'm trying to call fputcsv, script is printing only fields without header which is IP and should be printed also.

here is my code:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("data2.txt", "r");
if (!$handle) {
  exit;
}

$customers = array();

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

    if(preg_match('/-([0-9]*)-pdt.html.*rd:(.*)\|X/i',$line,$output)){
      $product = $output[1];
      $customer = $output[2];   

        if(!isset($customers[$customer])){

            $customers[$customer] = array($product);

          } else {
                if (!in_array($product, $customers[$customer])){

            $customers[$customer][] = $product;

                }
            }       
        }
    }
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'w+');
foreach ($customers as $customers[$customer]) 
{   
    fputcsv($file, $customers[$customer]);
}
var_dump ($customers);
fclose($handle);
```

this is my data result:

```
array (size=10)
  '164.38.32.100' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '21940504' (length=8)
      1 => string '21940524' (length=8)
  '86.11.76.246' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '10145712' (length=8)
  '185.31.96.130' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '10139358' (length=8)
      1 => string '10139458' (length=8)
  '2.126.213.238' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '10164438' (length=8)
```

here is the csv :

```
21940504    21940524
10145712    
10139358    10139458
10164438
```

I need to figure that out how to put IP at first column like this :

```
164.38.32.100 21940504  21940524
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what this is all about:

```
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
  ....
     $customer = $output[2];
  ....
} //end while loop, with $customer defined in it, 

foreach ($customers as $customers[$customer]) //<-- whats this about
{   
    fputcsv($file, $customers[$customer]);  //<-- this also makes no sense
}
```

the value of `$customer` will be from the last iteration of the while loop, if I counted brackets correctly.  I am pretty sure that is not what you want to be writing in the csv `fputcsv($file, $customers[$customer]);`.  And I never seen a foreach array use an assignment like that with an array Key  `as $customers[$customer])`

Try something like this instead:

```
 foreach ($customers as $ipAddress => $customer) 
 {   
     array_unshift($customer, $ipAddress); //prepend IP address to inner array
     fputcsv($file, $customer);
 }
```

This also makes no sense:

> script is printing only fields without header which is IP

Headers are the first row ( typically of a CSV ) they are the names of the columns, such as  `IPaddress`

> I need to figure that out how to put IP at first column like this :
>
> 164.38.32.100,21940504,21940524

Here IP is a column, not a header.  It's confusing, anyway I did my best to sort out what you want.

Or do you mean, that the other rows, somehow have a header in the array of data.   I would say, the IP is the "Top Level Array Key", the other data is the values of the nested array.

Comment: Sure, Glad I was able to sort out what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking into it.

Ip adress is showing now in csv file,

like this:

```
21940504    21940524    164.38.32.100
10145712    86.11.76.246    
10139358    10139458    185.31.96.130
10164438    2.126.213.238
```

however it is at the last place by append and I need it to be at the first column.

Comment: If you are talking to me, I already updated my answer with `array_unshift`  which will put it on the front.  Although I don't see the need for you to put this "comment" as a separate answer.